# What's the trouble on passing a List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> to a WebService?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

This is my `asmx` WebService method:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetHeader(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> signature_additional_parameters)
{
    return "ok";
}
```

but when I call it from another application:

```
var signature_additional_parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
signature_additional_parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("test", "my data"));

var header = MyWS.GetHeader(signature_additional_parameters);
```

it says *The best overloaded method match for 'WSArchieSocial.WSModuloSocial.GetHeader(WSArchieSocial.KeyValuePairOfStringString[])' has some invalid arguments*?

Why it use that `WSArchieSocial.KeyValuePairOfStringString[]`? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have a look at [How to Pass Name/Value Pairs to an ASMX Web Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788571/how-to-pass-name-value-pairs-to-an-asmx-web-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web service is expecting an array of `KeyValuePair`. Just call `ToArray` on your List and your error would be resolved.

```
var header = MyWS.GetHeader(signature_additional_parameters.ToArray());
```

I guess it has to do with the way you added reference for the service. You can specify the collection type while adding service reference, The default is array that is why it is treating your `List<KeyValuePair>` as an array.

You can select collection type, by going to Advanced when adding service. 
[image]

Comment: Uhm nothing happens. It prints the same error message :O

Comment: @markzzz, add the reference again, and select `GenericList` from Collection type, as show in the image.

Comment: I'm adding a Web Reference, not a Service Reference (the button below the second screen Add Web Reference). That DataType seems to be ignored :O

Comment: Tried using Service Reference: nothing change! Even with .ToArray() or  .ToList()

Comment: That's incredible: it won't work neither if I set `KeyValuePair<string, string>[]` on the WebService method ghgh